# How to work around Python List of Dictionary TypeError with only one item in the list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I get past a TypeError with a one item list?
I have this list of a dictionary:

```
    ADSR_Dbs = {'Tables' : (
    {'Table' : 'ACSL',
    'columns': ('ID','Loc','Pos')
    'type': ('int','varchar','varchar')
    }
)}
```

which produces the TypeError: string indices must be integers
when I try to do this:

```
for DBTables in ADSR_Dbs['Tables']:
    print("Table: " + DBTables['Table'])
```

But if there are more items in the list it's ok like:

```
ADSR_Dbs = {'Tables' : (
    {'Table' : 'ACSL',
    'columns': ('ID','Loc','Pos')
    'type': ('int','varchar','varchar')
    },
    {'Table':None,
    'columns':(None),
    'type':(None)
    }
)}
```

Sometimes the list has only one item in it, so how do I avoid the TypeError?

Comment: In the `for` loop you are iterating over the keys in the `ADSR_Dbs` dictionary. I guess you need to iterate over the key-value pairs with `.items()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Python, tuples are created with `()` parentheses. But these symbols have many another mentions: for functions, for logical blocks of code etc. So if one wants to create a one-element-tuple, one should write it as: `(element, )` with a comma so Python interpreter will know that it is really a tuple, not a code in parentheses. In your case, you have just an ordinary dict. If you want a tuple of dicts, you should write a comma:

```
ADSR_Dbs = {'Tables' : (
    {'Table' : 'ACSL',
    'columns': ('ID','Loc','Pos'),
    'type': ('int','varchar','varchar')
    },
     ^
     |
     +----------------- HERE
)}
```

So the code will be:

```
ADSR_Dbs = {'Tables' : (
    {'Table' : 'ACSL',
    'columns': ('ID','Loc','Pos'),
    'type': ('int','varchar','varchar')
    },
)}
for DBTables in ADSR_Dbs['Tables']:
    print("Table: " + DBTables['Table'])
```

> `Table: ACSL`

But when you have several elements in a tuple, Python will know that it is a tuple so your code starts to work when you have 2+ elements. Note, that lists don't have this problem. `[element]` is a one-element-list, you don't need a comma.

Comment: Adding the comma worked! It seems like some dirty code with the trailing comma, but good to know!!

Comment: "In Python, tuples are created with ()" they are not. Parentheses are require *sometimes* for disambiguation, but a comma is what makes a tuple